# In Android, control (play/pause) media player from external code

Tags: android, media-player

I'm very new to Android programming. As a first hobby project, I'd like to write a program to control the media player app, in particular play/pause (or toggle) or even better, fast forward/backward.  Is it possible to do this?  If yes, are there any tutorials or sample code?

Thanks very much.

**Clarification:** maybe I was not clear enough in my original question. I don't want to play audio/video inside my app, but I want to control other media player apps (says the default music app) from my app. For example, my app has only one button, if the default media player app is playing some music (in the background) and I push that button, the music is paused.

Comment: see solution here [medialplayer play/pause][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461056/android-media-player-play-pause-button/23147971#23147971

Answer (score 25):

The Following code is paused default Media Player via sendBroadcast:

```
   AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    

    if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) {

    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");

    i.putExtra("command", "pause");
    YourApplicationClass.this.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```

Comment: This broadcast seems to be from the code of the music player app from Google: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java. Still it seems like a few others work with it (but most don't). Mix Radio works, but Spotify, ... don't.

Comment: @Ramesh Akula -can you please add how to resume music after pause?

Comment: @AjitKumarDubey resume can be done by using 
i.putExtra("command", "togglepause");

Comment: for more commands check this : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/278aaed1eb37763f7dcb2364523db591014a9210/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java