# How to pause Video Player?

Tags: android, media-player

The answer given in [pausing MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518438/in-android-control-play-pause-media-player-from-external-code/) works perfectly well for a Music Player.
In similar way, how can we pause a Video Player? (the question is to pause the phone's default VideoPlayer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will simply redirect you to native video player, which by default has the ability to pause and play.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(//provide working url here)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Can you be little more specific? (by providing sample code)
I want to pause the VideoPlayer before launching my activity .

Comment: we have direct passed the intent so not possible pause before launch Activity But u can create  like this http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/playingVideo.html