# Android Media Player play/pause Button

Tags: android, media-player

In my project, I am playing music file in android media player by using the following code

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.myfile);
mPlayer.start();
```

the above is coded in the onclick of the play button.
I want to pause the playback by clicking the same button again.ie) single button for play/pause.
How shall i do this.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could use simple if-check to handle the pausing. Try this:

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mPlayer.pause();
} else {
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Please try this::**

```
final Button bPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
MediaPlayer song1 = MediaPlayer.create(tutorialFour.this, R.raw.fluet);
Button bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
bPlay.setWidth(10);

song1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            bPlay.setText("Play");


        }
    });

bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b = true;

            if (bPlay.getText().equals("Play") && b == true) {

                song1.start();

                bPlay.setText("Pause");
                b = false;
            } else if (bPlay.getText().equals("Pause")) {
                x = song1.getCurrentPosition();
                song1.pause();
                bPlay.setText("Resume");
                Log.v("log", "" + x);
                b = false;
            } else if (bPlay.getText().equals("Resume") && b == true) {
                song1.seekTo(x);
                song1.start();
                bPlay.setText("Pause");
                b = false;
            }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside the button click check for `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()`. This will return true if the media player is playing else false.

So now with this, flag value you can make a if statement and switch to play or pause like this,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaplayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaplayer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code takes care of your play/pause button click event along with forward and backward buttons for forward and backward seek on the seekbar provided (which is synchronized with the media track). Currently it plays just ONE song. However, you can add to that. This is my first media player using `mediaplayer class`, so you might find it a bit primitive. However if you need you can also check out the `VideoView` examples. It's apparently easier with `VideoView` as the standard media console is already present in the form of pre-defined widgets. so that makes designing the player much easier.

```
package in.org.Test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test12Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,Runnable {

    private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing"; 
    private static final String notPlaying = "Media has stopped Playing"; 

    private SeekBar seek;

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
     private ImageButton plus,minus;

    ImageButton im;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        plus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        minus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);


        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);


        player.setLooping(false); 
        im = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


        seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seek.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        seek.setProgress(0);
        seek.setMax(player.getDuration());
        new Thread(this).start();


        im.setOnClickListener(this);
        player.start(); 

        Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { int cu = player.getCurrentPosition();  player.seekTo(cu-5000); }});
        minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {int cu = player.getCurrentPosition();  player.seekTo(cu+5000);}});


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
        if(player.isPlaying())  {
        player.pause();

        Toast.makeText(this, notPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ImageButton img1=(ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

         }
        else
        {
            player.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ImageButton img1=(ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }   
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0; String s;
        int total = player.getDuration();
        while (player!=null && currentPosition<total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= player.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            

            seek.setProgress(currentPosition);


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 MediaPlayer mpE = MediaPlayer.create(GuitarTuner.this, R.raw.test2 );

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mpE.isPlaying()) {
                mpE.pause();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {

                mpE.start();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For pausing the `Mediaplayer`:

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length = Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

and for resuming the player from the position where it stopped lately is done by:

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

Comment: Genious Answer !

Answer (score 1):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//the song was previously saved in the raw folder. The name of the song is mylife (it's an mp3 file)
        final MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mylife);

```
    //      Play song
    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
        }
    });
    //      Pause song
    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    });

    //      Stop song - when you stop a song, you can't play it again. First you need to prepare it.

    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Please don't just dump code...explain your answer at least a little bit.  And take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = button.getText().toString();
            if (text.equals("play")){
                mediaPlayer.start();
                button.setText("pause");  //changing text
            }
            else if (text.equals("pause")){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                button.setText("play");  //changing text
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution. If mediaplayer is playing, display play button and pause the mediaplayer. If not playing, do the opposite.

```
         playBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //events on play buttons
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
        });
```