# How to pause a music player programmatically

Tags: android

I have used `MUSIC_PLAYER` in my application by starting like this:

```
Intent myint = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(myint);
```

And I want to pause this player. How do I do that?

```
import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread mtr = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Intent myint = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
                    startActivity(myint);
                    sleep(50000);
                    // Here I want to pause my application after those 50 seconds.
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    Intent myint = new Intent("nextscreen");
                    startActivity(myint);
                }
            }
        };
        mtr.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In [Samsung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung) devices, you can control the music player with these intents:

```
ICS:
"com.android.music.musicservicecommand.play"
"com.android.music.musicservicecommand.pause"
"com.android.music.musicservicecommand.next"
...

JB:
"com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.play"
"com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.pause"
"com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.next"
...

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.sec.android.app.music.musicservicecommand.pause"));
```

Another solution is requestAudioFocus in AudioManager (do not forget to release it with abandonAudioFocus). For example:

```
...
((AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).requestAudioFocus(listener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
...

...
((AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).abandonAudioFocus(listener);
...
```

Comment: What about other devices?

Comment: Mehradad, if you want to control music player with intents you should check manifest of the app. Each vendor provide different default music players and you can not be sure if you are using supported intents. Consider to use request/abandon AudioFocus but read documentation carefully.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Pausing the music player is an internal action inside the application available to the user exclusively, so it cannot be accessed/called from outside of the application.

You can, however, mute the music audio stream using the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class by calling `setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true)`.

Code sample:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

Comment: where i have to keep the line in the above code .it's showing error message

Comment: Put it after the call to the `sleep` method. Note that it won't close the media player, it will only mute it. If you want to play specific sounds and have full control on the player, use `MediaPlayer` instead.

Comment: but it's showing an error message that to create method for setStreamMute() ,what should i do now ?

Comment: the method setStreamMute(int boolean) is undefined for the type new Thread(){}

Comment: The method `setStreamMute` is of the type `AudioManager`, this is not how you should use it... I added a sample

Comment: it permanently muted the volume . i tested in my phone iam unable to increase the sound there after . what should i do now ?

Comment: call `setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false)` when you want to unmute.

Comment: everything is fine except , if i press mute function two times i have to unmute it again two times, how can i overcome this problem @Jong

Comment: Yes, that's how it works : "The mute requests for a given stream are cumulative: the AudioManager can receive several mute requests from one or more clients and the stream will be unmuted only when the same number of unmute requests are received." You can check if the stream is muted, and if it is - don't mute again.

Comment: i need to discuss something with u may i have your facebook profile id ? @Jong

Answer (score 2):

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634606/2826409), you can send broadcast to pause or stop the default music player very easy.