# how to detect if another app is playing audio

Tags: java, android

I am making a music player app and I want my app to stop music automatically when a video plays
and i am searching for a long time and I didn't find any thing

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518438/in-android-control-play-pause-media-player-from-external-code/7634606#7634606 has the code that you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Android, control (play/pause) media player from external code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518438/in-android-control-play-pause-media-player-from-external-code)